# how to exclude few inputs from resetting in a html form

Tags: javascript, html

There is a form with 2 inputs and a button that resets the inputs. When the button is clicked, how can I make first input unchanged (i.e it should not reset the value). How can I achieve it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Add-More example - fileuploader - Innostudio.de</title>
        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="file-loading" style="margin: 50px;">
            <form>
                <input id="no_reset" type="text">
                <input id="input-fa" type="text">
                <button type="reset" onclick="removeReset()">
                    <i class="fas fa-sync"></i>submit
                 </button>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            function removeReset() {
                //it doesn't work
                document.getElementById("no_reset").value = "dont reset";
            }
        </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use the button type="reset". Just use JS to reset the ones that you want to instead.

Comment: I've too many inputs in a form and there are only 2 inputs that should not reset. Thats why I am looking if theres a way.

Comment: Can;t you just setup a js loop to go through all inputs and reset, and then skip the ones with  no_reset class?

Comment: ok tq. I was planning to do that but want to know if theres any better way.

Comment: Ah ok, I don't think there is as the reset button is a HTML element that won't let you add any restrictions into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of input, you can reset all fields except ones with a custom attribute.

Take a look at a sample vanilla js implementation :

```js
function customReset()
{
    var fieldsToReset = document.querySelectorAll("input:not([data-noreset='true'])")
  for(var i=0;i<fieldsToReset.length;i++){
    fieldsToReset[i].value = null;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="txt1" name="txt1" /> : should reset<br/>
  <input id="txt2" name="txt2" /> : should reset<br/>
  <input id="txt3" name="txt3" /> : should reset<br/>
  <input id="txt4" name="txt4" data-noreset="true" /> : <strong>won't reset</strong><br/>
  <button type="button" onclick="customReset()">
    Reset
  </button>
</form>
```

Pay attention to the `type="button"` attribute. This is required to neither reset the form nor submit it.